# PHP - check the spelling of a word: How to install/configure aspell libraries

Tags: php

On Windows7 + WAMP-2.211 + PHP-5.3.0 I wanted to install **aspell** so I went to http://www.php.net/manual/en/pspell.installation.php & downloaded the libraries but I did not understand how could I install/configure this libraries & how to use?

I also tried, just enabled **php_pspell** extension & followed http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-check.php example but

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function pspell_new() in
>   D:\wamp\www\spell\index.php on line 2

error occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PEAR/PECL already you could try installing Enchant http://pecl.php.net/package/enchant (I've not used it myself, sorry)